# Excel, change date format from Fri Jun 30 00:00:00 EDT 2017 to YYYYMMDD in cell

Tags: excel

How can I change the date from `Fri Jun 30 00:00:00 EDT 2017`to `20170630` in the cell not with the format.

Comment: that form of date is not recognized as a date, so it will be hard for any formatting to change it

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use formula, not formatting, to obtain the desired date format, you can use

```
=TEXT("Fri Jun 30 00:00:00 EDT 2017", "YYYYMMDD")
```

In reference mode, if the date is in cell A1, then

```
=TEXT(A1,"YYYYMMDD")
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom formatting.

Type this into the formatting box:

`yyyymmdd`

See below.

[image]

Comment: @excelguy Just tried on mine and the cell changed to the desired format. Perhaps is there conditional formatting applied to that cell preventing it from allowing the date format to change?

Comment: @excelguy, it probably due to your system does not recognize "Fri Jun 30 00:00:00 EDT 2017" as a date. if yes, then just cut some of the unnecessary section away e.g. 00:00:00 EDT, using the `REPLACE` or `SUBSTITUTE` function